# read_chunk not working with shiny widget in rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to use function read_chunk along with a shiny widget in Rmarkdown report. The output is an HTML document and runtime: shiny. 
When I run the chunks individually it works perfectly fine. But when I use 
 `read_chunk()` in my script and then run_chunk t run only one chunk of the source chunk, it throws an error. What I feel is there is a way to interact shiny widget and read chunks. Please help how do I do this.

Error:

> Warning: Error in parse: :2:0: unexpected end of input 1:
>   read_chunk(paste0(params$code_path,"chunk_name.R")

the chunk that I am using is saved at '/loaction/chunk_v1.R'

```
## @knitr iris_sub
#######################################################################################################################################
#######################################################################################################################################

iris_subset <- subset(iris, Species=='setosa')
```

#

````
---
params:
  code_chunk: '/location/'

title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown



```{r iris_sub}
read_chunk(paste0(params$code_chunk,"chunk_v1.R"))
```


```{r iris_plot, echo=FALSE}
sample_his <- function(dataset_name){

library(shiny)
shinyApp(
ui=fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Iris Dataset"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("p", "Select column of iris dataset:",
                   list("Sepal.Length"='a', "Sepal.Width"='b', "Petal.Length"='c', "Petal.Width"='d')),
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
),

server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    if(input$p=='a'){
      i<-1
    }

    if(input$p=='b'){
      i<-2
    }

    if(input$p=='c'){
      i<-3
    }

    if(input$p=='d'){
      i<-4
    }

    x    <- dataset_name[, i]

    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}
)}
```

## Including Plots



```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
sample_his(iris)
```
````

Comment: please provide sample code so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: Added the code!